# Add space below last element of Table view in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to add some extra space after the last element in the table view cell.

In android reccycler view, the same thing can be achieved by

```
android:paddingBottom="8dp"
 android:clipToPadding="false"
```

[image: Table view last item]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to add *insets* to your tableView . Try the following code

```
let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 50, right: 0)
tableView.contentInset = insets
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's always visible even I am @ my first cell in the list...I need only that space after my last cell

Comment: What do you mean by _visible even I am @ my first cell_, the space will only be shown when you scroll to the end of the tableView and reach the last cell, not before as we are _setting the inset according to the content of the tableView_.

Comment: @EbinJoy . Thank you . Happy to help :)

Answer (score 4):

Add datasource and delegate for your tableview and utilize following delegate methods:
- `heightForFooterInSection` & `viewForFooterInSection`

```
// set view for footer
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 40)) // assuming 40 height for footer.
    footerView.backgroundColor = <Some Color>
    return footerView
}

// set height for footer
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 40
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's always visible even I am @ my first cell in the list...I need only that space after my last cell

Comment: The footer is always shown after the last cell in the table. If you have 1,000 cells, the footer is after the 1,000 cell and won't be seen until you scroll till down. If you have 4 cells, it is shown after the 4th cell.
I suspect that the footer you see at bottom is not actually a footer but its the view behind the table view as Table View may not be covering the whole height of the view.

Comment: Please try to give some distinguishable color say (UIColor.red or blue) and see where the footer is coming up.

Comment: Sure will check, thkz

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/17mGK7kThMpIvnURWhr-ZF-_ZZ4fz8uCY/view?usp=sharing .  This happens

Comment: Works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 4):

When you use content inset for add padding it may create some issue, when no data available in tableView.

**Try this**

Simply and the view in a `tableFooterView` for the padding in the bottom of `tableView`.

```
//Add Padding in the bottom of tableview

let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 20))
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
tableView.tableFooterView = view
```

Answer (score 2):

Add **tableFooterView** in tableview.

```
let tableFooterView  = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 20))

  tableFooterView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

  tableView.tableFooterView = tableFooterView
```

Answer (score 2):

***Swift 5***

I tried adding tableView inset at first but it didn't work in my case. Rather I tried adding footerView at the end of UItableView.

```
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 100))
        return footerView
    }

// Incase you have more then one sections. you will add at the end of last section.

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        if section == exercisesArray.count-1 {
            return 60
        }else{
            return 0
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Going off of a previous answer, you need to check if it's the last cell.

```
let bottomPadding = 8

if (self?.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) ?? 0) - 1 == row {
    let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: bottomPadding, right: 0)
    strongSelf.tableView.contentInset = insets
}
```

Assuming you're editing the first section.